# is there any compatibility issues when migrating to upper version?

Tags: jquery

My program uses jQuery.
Now, I'm using jQuery version 1.9.1 and want to migrate to version 3.1.
Is there any compatibility issues??? I already have hundreds of javascript files that uses jQuery. So, if it has any compatibility issue, I'll give up migrating..

Comment: What is the purpose of migration?

Comment: If you use third party plugins in your program you may get some problem ?

Comment: Smit Raval -the purpose is to use upper version of javascript library..

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery migrate [`jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate), it should be added in the following order.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<!-- Old Jquery -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery migrate -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js"></script>
<!-- Jquery libraries -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

If you still run into issues, refer to [migration docs](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/) or tackle each issue manually.